# Titanic Dataset. Logits and Labels of different shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle

I am currently building a DNN for the Titanic Dataset classification. During that process, I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1,5] and labels shape [5]
```

My code can be found here:

https://github.com/isaac-altair/Titanic-Dataset/blob/master/Titanic%2BProject.ipynb

I tried reshaping logits using the np.reshape(logits, (-1, 1)), but it would not work.

Thanks

Comment: Fixed the error by writing "logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 1])". I will post more if I have anymore errors.

Comment: Now I get: 'None of [[681 475 699 189 686]] are in the [index]'

Comment: Fixed previous error. Get new one, "targets[3] is out of range".

Comment: Please close the question as it has been solved. I will ask another question in a new post.

Thanks